# Sublime 3 text editor displaying the file name twice

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, text-editor

I am using MacBook Air. I install the XAMPP success and it's working perfectly. Now I open the folder in sublime text editor 3 but I am getting the file name twice.

For example

```
._test1.php
._test2.php
._test3.php
._test4.php
test1.php
test2.php
test3.php
test4.php
```

Screen shoot

[image]

[image]

I am using the latest sublime editor. Would you help me out on this issue?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe hidden files? check if folder has `hidden files`

Comment: @Roy, In the folder I am not getting the ._test1.php files. I checked there is no hidden file.

Answer (score 2):

## Your code should be:

```
{
   "font-size":13,
   "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db", "._*"]
}
```

> **"._" Files** These invisible files are "resource fork" segments of files
>   that are being created on the external volume. In Macintosh
>   filesystems (HFS and HFS ) there is support for two types of file
>   information: one is the resource fork, and the other is the data fork.
>   The data fork will contain user-supplied information such as the text
>   of a word document, and the resource fork will contain information
>   about the document such as author, document-specific preferences, and
>   other metadata.
>
> In Mac OS X filesystems these forks are treated as one file, and
>   appear as such; however, resource forks are not supported on many
>   filesystems, including those used on Windows machines (SMB and NTFS).
>   As such, when users copy files to these systems the resource fork can
>   be lost. Therefore Apple has built a file-handling mechanism into OS X
>   which automatically splits the resource and data forks into two files
>   when copied to disks that do not support resource forks.

To exclude these files into **Sublime** you have to add `._*` to the  `file_exclude_patterns` in the **Sublime preferences**

```
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db", "._*"]
```

Comment: I added the one more screenshot.  In which menu I have to check?

Comment: I checked in settings and I found 
    "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db", "*.sublime-workspace"],

Comment: Now I am trying to add but it's not allowing me to add. I am not getting any error.

Comment: Just add `"._*"` in the array

Comment: Put them in the right side of sublime. (user settings)

Comment: Should I add the whole array or only add "._*"?

Comment: Try adding the whole array.

Comment: I added the whole array and save then I got an error, I attached in the question. Please check it once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191729/discussion-between-questionbank-and-roy).